# PowerPoint presentation in web Browser without using Google Docs

Tags: javascript, css, html

I trying to display my ppt for long time where the screen should run continuously in web page without using **Google Docs** or **Skype Drive** where the ppt file and html page is in my local folder but it is not showing in web page. The code is below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="lp.ppt" width="800px" heigt="600px" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

can anyone help to display ppt in html page.

Comment: You cannot just "show" a Power Point presentation in the browser without using a library or plugin to do so. Browsers do not understand Power Point presentations format.

Comment: google ppt js - first result = https://github.com/SheetJS/js-ppt - may work, may reprogram your VCR, don't know

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the official [View Office documents online](https://products.office.com/en-GB/office-online/view-office-documents-online?legRedir=true&CorrelationId=b28c7173-79a2-4fb7-a1eb-9e75651fd1a1)

For embedding you can simply use code like below:

```
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src={urlencode(site-to-ppt)}' width='962px' height='565px' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you. But it is not displaying the ppt in web browser using html page.

Comment: Did you followed the instructions provided here: https://products.office.com/en-GB/office-online/view-office-documents-online?legRedir=true&CorrelationId=b28c7173-79a2-4fb7-a1eb-9e75651fd1a1 If still issue then post your code here or create JSfiddle

Comment: Here the code where I am using
<iframe src=https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=%20D%3A%5CUsers%5Ckollupothu.r%5CDesktop%5Cppt%5Clp.ppt' width='962px' height='565px' frameborder='0'></iframe>

Comment: the path in the iframe is broken, thats why its not working. Create a url from here: https://products.office.com/en-GB/office-online/view-office-documents-online?legRedir=true&CorrelationId=b28c7173-79a2-4fb7-a1eb-9e75651fd1a1

Comment: Can you share the ppt url

Comment: will never work with old url, you'll have to upload to server..url must be with http

Comment: this is my folder path D:\Users\kollupothu.r\Desktop\ppt\lp.ppt and this is url create  https: //view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?
src=D%3A%5CUsers%5Ckollupothu.r%5CDesktop%5Cppt%5Clp.ppt. But  it is not working too.

Comment: Read my comment..it will never work with local path..you must upload somewhere on server and use that path

Comment: I am not using any server at present. Can give what are the server can I use.